# Phonegap get camera blackberry not working also place image inline and save to library

Tags: api, blackberry, cordova, camera

Get Camera - Blackberry and save to library advise please
I am using the following code to get pictures from the camera and place them in the app.
However it is not working on Blackberry (camera does not open) `onclick="takePicture();"`
Also I want to save images to user library as well.

Have found a number of different ways to do this is this any good ? or is there a better method

```
function takePicture() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(
function(uri) {
var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
img.style.visibility = "visible";
img.style.display = "block";
img.src = uri;
document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
},
function(e) {
console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
},
{ quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
};
```

Comment: is the uri correctly pointed?